# Is there a tutorial out there to demonstrate developing web services using metro and tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, java-metro-framework

I've been given an assignment on working with web services using metro and tomcat.  I'm aware that other JAX-WS implementations and containers exists, but I'm required to use those technologies.

I'm trying to find a straightforward tutorial on developing web services with metro and tomcat using eclipse.  I found this, http://metro.java.net/guide/Developing_with_Eclipse.html.  I changed the glassfish steps to use Tomcat instead, but when I run it, I get a 404.  I'm guessing my issue has to do with Step 2.  I create a new class, but is there something different I should be doing?  Thanks!

Comment: The Metro Eclipse guide is now at http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#developing-with-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

This requires you to

1. copy webservices-api.jar from the metro lib to the endorsed folder in your jre/lib
2. copy webservices-api.jar from the metro lib to the endorsed folder in your tomcat directory
3. modify catalina properties' shared.loader=%METRO_HOME%/lib/*.jar

This should take care of your issue.

Thanks
Ramesh